# Azure search indexer indexes entire Cosmos db data source every time

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

I have Azure Search Index based on top of Cosmos Db. All worked as a charm while my data source was configured without custom query (indexer crawled only new data on each run).

Now I need to define a query like the following:

```
SELECT c.id, 1 as itemType, c._ts FROM c WHERE c._ts >= @HighWaterMark ORDER BY c._ts
```

The issue is that each time my indexer runs it collects a complete data source. Data source is 4000 items, the number of new items is 5, data is not changed.

I found that using the following query respects previous progress (indexer works as it did without the query):

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c._ts >= @HighWaterMark ORDER BY c._ts
```

Also I tried to load @HighWaterMark as one of my fields and found that @HighWaterMark is always -1.

**UPDATE**

My data is unchangeable. Therefore I didn't use data change detection policy. But enabling this policy makes the indexer work as intended. I haven't found any info about such dependency between policy and indexer work in Microsoft docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new indexer and specify the query the way you need:

[image]

more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-cosmosdb

However, if you want to keep the Azure Cognitive Search Index updated, a better approach would be combine Cosmos Db Change Feed + Azure Functions, then, send the updated / new documents do your Azure Cognitive Search Index.

[image]

More info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-functions

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/azure-cosmosdb-change-feed/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But it doesn't help. I specified the query and it works. I have a different problem.
Regarding the 'push' model suggestion: I have azure function to update index on flight and use indexer mostly as a last line of defense. But again it doesn't help with original problem